# Hierarchy query with 3 tables

Tags: oracle, hierarchy

I am not able to understand how to achieve a hierarchy accessing 3 tables. That is, I have Table1, Table2 and Table3 where:

```
Table1 (ID_table1, name_c, size)

Table2 (ID_table2, ID_table1, name_l, size)

Table3 (ID_table3, ID_table1, ID_table2, name_d, size)
```

How do I make a hierarchy with all this information? I've looked for it but only found solutions with information into a single table.

*EDIT: I edited the information in the tables because they do not express myself

Comment: What kind of hierarchies would you want to build? Standard parent-child relationships are build in a single table. And hierarchies in that idea are on multiple levels (think manager-employees relations). What data structures do you like to model with your tables?

Comment: You need to exaplain the relationship better, is it `Table1 PARENT OF Table2 PARENT OF Table3`?

Comment: @Marian, I want to build a hierarchy in which table1 stick with level 1, Table2 and Table3 as Level2 as level 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never tried anything like that, but what if you UNION your three tables into one, and then do a "one-table hierarchical query" on the result of that?

```
WTIH alltabs as
    (Select 'T1' as src, Table1.ID, NULL AS ID_table1, NULL as ID_table2, Table1.name, Table1.size
    from Table1
    union
    Select 'T2' as src, Table2.ID, Table2.ID_table1, NULL as ID_table2, Table2.name, Table2.size
    from Table2
    union
    Select 'T3' as src, Table3.ID, Table3.ID_table1, Table3.ID_table2, Table3.name, Table3.size
    from Table3)
Select *
from alltabs
/*you can have an optional STARTING WITH clause here, but it's not clear from your question what that would be*/
connect by (id = id_table1 and (src = 'T1' or src = 'T2'))
        or (id = id_table2 AND (src = 'T2' or src = 'T3'))
```

(I'm assuming that the relationship is `Table1 PARENT OF Table2 PARENT OF Table3`).

Comment: excellent query but I needed an improvement if it were possible. And I have to read all this information in php and I have to pass first the father and correspondingly their children, and so and then I can move on to other parent. If I understand what I mean?

Let's think in level 1 have the A and D, and at level 2 we have that A causes B and C and D do not originate anything. This query you created, first shows of all level 1 and level 2 of them then, and I wanted him to give me the level 1 when corresponding with their children. Got it?

Comment: @zmki: Oh that's a little different... Not sure the best way to do that. You might have to change the query in the `WITH` clause to use `INNER JOINS` between the tables instead of unions, but then you'd also have to think carefully about what data you select. Hmm... Or maybe you could add an `ORDER BY` in `alltabs` to correct it...?

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Frusterated's answer<sup>+1</sup>, but with a few different assumptions.

```
drop table table1;
drop table table2;
drop table table3;

create table table1 (ID Number(3), Name Varchar2(10), SizeX number(3));
create table table2 (ID Number(3), ID_table1 Number(3), Name Varchar2(10), SizeX number(3));
create table table3 (ID Number(3), ID_table2 Number(3), Name Varchar2(10), SizeX number(3));

insert into table1 values (1,'a',1);
   insert into table2 values (10, 1, 'a-a', 3);
   insert into table2 values (11, 1, 'a-b', 4);
      insert into table3 values (100, 11, 'a-b-a',8);
      insert into table3 values (101, 11, 'a-b-b',9);
insert into table1 values (2,'b',2);
   insert into table2 values (12, 2, 'b-a', 5);
   insert into table2 values (13, 2, 'b-b', 6);
      insert into table3 values (102, 13, 'b-b-a',10);
   insert into table2 values (14, 2, 'b-c', 7);
commit;

SELECT id, parent, name, sizex, level
FROM
(
   SELECT id, null parent, name, sizex FROM Table1
   UNION ALL
   SELECT id, id_table1, name, sizex FROM TABLE2
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT id, id_table2, name, sizex FROM TABLE3
)
START WITH parent IS NULL
CONNECT BY (prior id = parent);
```

Comment: I love the whitespace utilization for hierarchy simulation :). Thumb up!

Comment: This will work only with the additional assumption that the ids are unique accross the 3 tables.

Comment: @Leigh Riffel I wrote id and name in both tables, but for different tables they have different names. I'll edit the initial post to best see fit

Comment: Renaming the name column is a simple thing, but Vincent is correct - the ids must be unique across tables for this to work.

Comment: ok, I test it better tomorrow and just say something to all of you, since I can not test it today

Comment: @LeighRiffel, you say "CONNECT BY (prior id = parent);" what id? from select? If this is the case, does not work

Comment: I'm sorry this does not work for you.  What is different about your data or intended results that is not represented in the demonstration above?  I created an SQL Fiddle for it as well -> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/423f7/1